# SQL Server stored procedure return type wrong

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that works fine in SQL. The output type is a string.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [gis].[usp_GetNextUp_suffix] 
    @TableName varchar(50), 
    @id_w_suffix varchar(20) OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @id int, @suffix varchar(6)

    SELECT @id = Next_FacilityID 
    FROM dbo.Next_up 
    WHERE table_name = @TableName

    SELECT @suffix = Suffix 
    FROM dbo.Next_up 
    WHERE table_name = @TableName

    SET @id_w_suffix = @suffix + CONVERT(varchar, @id) + 'A'

    UPDATE dbo.Next_up 
    SET Next_FacilityID = @id + 1 
    WHERE table_name = @TableName
GO
```

However SQL Server Management Studio lists its return type as an integer, even though it returns a valid string.

[image]

When I pull the stored procedure into .net LINQ object it errors as it too is expecting a integer instead of string.

How do I alter the stored procedure to specify the correct return type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server stored procedures return *int*.  Always.  This is a status value.  If you want to return a different value, use a stored function.

You will simply get a type error of some sort when you try to run the procedure.

In this case, you cannot create a function because you have an `UPDATE` statement.  So, you have to return the output value using a parameter.

Comment: I understand now,  thank you. In .NET I changed the output variable to a reference and it worked as expected.